# Triggering Javascript Text and Pic Preview on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a text preview function which displays the title the user inputs with styled CSS, as they are typing. When the user saves the page, switches off the app, and tries to edit their text later, their saved text is not displayed on page load.

Only when a user presses a key does their saved text appear on screen.

**Default text: YOUR TITLE HERE**

**User saves: My Hydroponic farm.**

*10 minutes later, user reloads page, sees:*

**Default text: YOUR TITLE HERE.**

Presses a key, sees his saved text:

**My Hydroponic Farm**

The JS does not trigger until a key is pressed. It should trigger on page load.

```
  $(function() {
$(".pf_text_in").keyup(function() {
    var pf_text_in = $(this).val();
    $(".text_preview").html(pf_text_in);
    return false;
});
});

    $(function() {
$(".pf_text_in2").keyup(function() {
    var pf_text_in = $(this).val();
    $(".text_preview2").html(pf_text_in);
    return false;
});
});
```

*

The pic preview has the same problem. Saved pics are not displayed on page reload. Only the default placeholder jpgs are displayed.

```
 $(".imgInp").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});

function readURL(input) {
  var $formPic = $(input).siblings('img');
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $formPic.attr('src', e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

Is there a way to make both functions trigger on page load?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following:

```
$(function() {
    // Trigger events on load
    $(".pf_text_in").keyup();
    $(".pf_text_in2").keyup();
    $(".imgInp").change();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try that, but Im not exactly sure what's going on there. Could you explain it in your answer?

Comment: You have each of your functions (that you want to run on load) bound to events that need to be triggered (such as pressing a key). The code I gave manually triggers those events, and the function it is wrapped in makes sure that happens on load.

Comment: That is clearer now. I couldn't see where you were triggering it at first.

Comment: Quite a few of the event functions in jQuery are shortcuts for a trigger event if they're called with no parameters.